# Monitor directory to not allow to create files with certain extension

Tags: delphi, file, directory, locking, blocking

Is it possible in **Delphi** to create an application that would **monitor** certain **directory** or directories to not allow system to create **file** with some specified **extensions**, including renaming existing files to such **blocked** extensions? Or possible to allow to create/rename files with just **allowed** set of extensions? The solution should include monitoring of all sub-directories...

Comment: It's the task for driver and those cannot be written in Delphi.

Comment: Questions like this always make me wonder why..

Comment: @TLama - I believe there is a way to use some "hook" to monitor it out of driver...

Comment: @GolezTrol - It is for virtual machine that is used exclusively for internet connection applications (browser, email, etc.) and share just part of disk space with host. Internet connection is disabled in non-virtual environment. This monitoring application should serve as "anti-virus" alternative to protect viruses to attack host from virtual machine environment.

Comment: Yes, [`you can monitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx) changes, but that's the easier half of your question. To prevent system against creating files with certain extensions, that's what you'll need a driver.

Comment: @TLama - Maybe not. If I setup no permission to open and execute files in such directory in virtual machine, then virus cannot be executed in VM and "monitoring" will be enough fast to quarantine such file(s).

Comment: Yes, but it won't be 100% safe. Every serious security application for this kind of protection has a FS driver just for being 100% sure there won't be any *maybe* ;-)

Comment: Perhaps you can implement network server in Delphi over FTP, WebDAV or CIFS protocol, then use it as share folder in your VM. Thas that server of yours would filter what is allowed and what not. Maybe there are also ready-made servers for which you can create plugins. Dunno if IIS support WebDAV

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Looking for AV alternative solution

Comment: I can't imagine why. Anyway, you can get to work writing a driver!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Because AV is not 100% safe solution. I can write a virus today that will go thru...

Comment: But the fact you are even asking this question indicates that you very likely can't write your own tool that would be any better. In fact odds are very high that your own tool would be far worse.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I never wrote that it will be me who is going to write such application. I am looking for advice that can be further analysed and later implemented by team. Anyway, thank you for your time and comments.